# How to expand the QTabWidget's tab bar?

Tags: qt

[image]

I have a QTabWidget Like this, I put the tab-bar to the west side.
And now my question is, how could I expand the tabs so that they use all the space on the tab bar? In stead of leaving the bottom left area blank?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by setting property in the style sheet:

```
tabWidget->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab { min-width: 100px; }");
```

But it won't resize the strings, so you better make your own widget with all elements that you need. I mean, to create your own view you can add elements at.